# php:composer auto loading not working with multiple directories inside src folder

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, php-7

Here is my folder structure

[image]

in my `package/index.php` look like this

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use HelloWorld\SayHello;

use Test\First;

 //works fine
 SayHello::world();

//returns classnot found error
 First::sayTest();
```

In my composer.json' i've included the following.

```
"autoload": {
     "psr-0": {
       "HelloWorld": "src/"
  }
}
```

But i got the following error in `First::sayTest()` line

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Test\First' not found

But the class `First.php` exists under `src\Test` folder.

```
namespace Test;
class First
{
    public static function sayTest()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Change `composer.json` to read:

```
"autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
       "": "src/"
  }
}
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload` to regenerate `vendor/autoload.php`.

Read more about the [autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) section of [`composer.json`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md).

Comment: This is actually bad advice, because your autoloading stated that ALL classes may be found in `src`, which is not true for most of them. You can add as many namespace prefixes and directories as you want, anything longer than `""` is better that your solution.

Answer (score 4):

You only declared that one prefix resides in `src`. Add another one:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "HelloWorld": "src/",
        "Test": "src/"
    }
}
```

Also note that when you are using namespaces, PSR-4 is better suited:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "HelloWorld\\": "src/HelloWorld/",
        "Test\\": "src/Test"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your composer.json contains some entry, which makes it load HelloWorld, but there is no such entry for the folder "Test".

Maybe it would help to copy your First.php to the HelloWorld-folder and change your reference in package.index.php.

Comment: How cani make an entry for `Test` folder in composer.json